# Delphi 6 TListView and SubItemImages Not Transparent

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I have a ListView where each row is displaying an alternate row color (e.g., white row, then light green row, then white row).

An `imagelist` has been assigned to the listview so that it display images down the left hand side.

The problem I have is when I use the `imagelist` and set the `subitemimage` to display an item in one of the other columns the image does not appear transparent.

How can I make these subitem images transparent?

Comment: Are you using theme manager? What colour format for your image list?

Comment: Out of curiosity. How to get display a different color in each row?

Comment: I had not picked up on that. Going to need code I think. In which case the question is not complete. What we ideally need is a complete program that illustrates the issue. Otherwise we have to try and write one, guessing at what the asker's code is.

Comment: @user Stack Overflow works best when you participate. Don't ask a question and then go away. By the time you come back we'll all have lost interest.